# gunicorn slower than flask development server

Tags: flask, gunicorn

My Flask application has a simple feature with a textarea where you input HTML and clicking on a button will strip all the HTML tags and return the text inside the HTML into another textarea, say Text.

When I run my application with:

```
app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port='8000')
```

it works very fast and smooth. But when I run it with gunicorn like this:

```
gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --log-file=- myapp.app:app
```

after I click the button 'HtmlToText' it takes too much time to return the text value and the larger the HTML the longest it takes.

Context:

The button is a simple JQuery function that does a GET request to `0.0.0.0:8000/htmltotext`, that view get's the HTML as a querystring parameter `/htmltotext?html=<head>Hi</head>` and returns a JSON `{text: "Hi"}`

What would be the reason for gunicorn being so slow in this issue ?

Comment: One possible issue is that there might be multiple gunicorn servers running? If you run ps aux|grep "gunicorn", does anything come up? I ran into a similar issue where I was only killing one worker, and gunicorn would respawn another to maintain the worker count I had specified.

Comment: @phouse512 yes there is other gunicorn servers running, but they are meant to, I can't kill them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, what was happening here is that gunicorn had this issue:

```
Bad Request

Request Line is too large (7385 > 4094)
```

Since the request was too large it was never happening.

The fix:

```
gunicorn --limit-request-line 0
```

0 means unlimited.