# Gunicorn Slows Flask Execution Considerably with Vue Reference

Tags: python, flask, vue.js, gunicorn, pipenv

I'm using Gunicorn to run a very basic Flask application (through pipenv) which is referenced by a Vue website (so basic it's not much more complicated than this MCVE).

---

**Pipfile**:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[dev-packages]

[packages]
flask = "*"
flask-cors = "*"
flask-pymongo = "*"
gunicorn = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.5"
```

**wsgi.py**:

```
from helloworld import application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

**helloworld.py**:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

import json

application = Flask(__name__)
CORS(application)

application.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'helloworld'
mongo = PyMongo(application, config_prefix='MONGO')

@application.route("/greet")
def hello():
    someone = mongo.db.people.find_one({},{"_id":0})
    return json.dumps(someone)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5432)
```

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p class="paragraph" id="app">{{ greeted }}!</p>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      greeted: ''
    },
    created () {
      fetch('http://0.0.0.0:5432/greet')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {this.greeted = json.name})
    }
  })
</script>
```

(the call to `mongo.db.people.find_one({},{"_id":0})` returns `{"name":"World"}`)

---

When I run this using the Flask development server:

```
pipenv run python helloworld.py
```

The website gets the value quickly on hard refresh.  However, if I run this through Gunicorn instead:

```
pipenv run gunicorn -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:5432 wsgi
```

It can take **several** seconds (sometimes on the order of minutes) to return the data.

*What causes this behavior?*

For reference, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985382/gunicorn-slower-than-flask-development-server) question is similar by title, but had a different problem.

**EDIT**: If I let the server run long enough, I get these messages:

```
[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:XXXXX)
```

**EDIT 2**: Changing the worker type to gevent seems to resolve the problem:

```
pipenv run gunicorn --worker-class gevent -w 3 -b 0.0.0.0:5432 wsgi
```

I'm unsure why (I'm not doing anything that should lead to blocking for dozens of seconds).  Also, changing to gevent leads to this warning:

> /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/FlaskApp-XXXXX/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py:65: MonkeyPatchWarning: Monkey-patching ssl after ssl has already been imported may lead to errors, including RecursionError on Python 3.6. Please monkey-patch earlier. See https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1016
>     monkey.patch_all(subprocess=True)